# Possible to combine apollo queries (within nuxt?)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I am using nuxt and apollo together with: https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module

I have a working GraphQL query (tested in GraphiQL):
(Because I want to fetch the info about my page and also some general SEO information)

```
{
  entries(section: [pages], slug: "my-page-slug") {
    slug
    title
  }
  seomatic(uri: "/") {
    metaTitleContainer
    metaTagContainer
    metaLinkContainer
    metaScriptContainer
    metaJsonLdContainer
  }
}
```

I want to fetch this data as well with apollo in nuxt:

So I tried:

```
<script>
import page from '~/apollo/queries/page'
import seomatic from '~/apollo/queries/seomatic'

export default {
  apollo: {
    entries: {
      query: page,
      prefetch: ({ route }) => ({ slug: route.params.slug }),
      variables() {
        return { slug: this.$route.params.slug }
      }
    },
    seomatic: {
      query: seomatic,
      prefetch: true
    }
  },
…
```

If I do that I will get an error message:

```
GraphQL error: Cannot query field "seomatic" on type "Query".
```

I then found this issue
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/issues/648
and I would like to know if ths could be a problem of the apollo nuxt module.
Because following that fix indicated in the issue does not resolve anything.

I further tried to combine the two calls into one:

```
fragment SeoMaticFragment on Root {
  seomatic(uri: "/") {
    metaTitleContainer
    metaTagContainer
    metaLinkContainer
    metaScriptContainer
    metaJsonLdContainer
  }
}

query myQuery($slug: String!) {
  entries(section: [pages], slug: $slug) {
    slug
    title
  }

  SeoMaticFragment
}
```

`~/apollo/queries/page.gql`

But this would first throw an error

> fragment Unknown type "Root"

1. So what is the best way to combine?
2. Why are the requests failing
3. is there an option to activate batching like described here: https://blog.apollographql.com/query-batching-in-apollo-63acfd859862

-

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
 // ... other options ...
 shouldBatch: true,
});
```

thank you so much in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a solution to this problem.
I found out that the `result` hook in vue-apollo solves this problem:

Example code that works:

```
<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const query = gql`
{
    entries(section: [pages], slug: "my-example-page-slug") {
        slug
        title
    }
    seomatic(uri: "/") {
        metaTitleContainer
        metaTagContainer
        metaLinkContainer
        metaJsonLdContainer
    }
}
`

export default {
    data: () => {
        return {
            page: false,
            seomatic: {}
        }
    },
    apollo: {
        entries: {
            query,
            prefetch: ({ route }) => ({ slug: route.params.slug }),
            variables() {
                return { slug: this.$route.params.slug }
            }
        },
        result(result) {
            this.entries = result.data.entries
            this.seomatic = result.data.seomatic
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: True that. I did find that solution as well, I just totally forgot about my question here.

Comment: Did you mean to put the result hook inside the entries query?